# When initializing an array, can variables be inside braces?

Tags: c

I am new to C and have found that it is common to initialize arrays with constants. I'm curious, is the following code legal?

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int array[3] = {a, b, c};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the lifetime of the variables.

If they are static variables, the initializer must be constant expression.

```c
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int array[] = { a, b, c };   // XXX Error

int main( void ) {
}
```

If they are automatic variables, this is allowed.

```c
int main( void ) {
   int a = 1;
   int b = 2;
   int c = 3;
   int array[] = { a, b, c };   // ok
}
```

> C23 §6.7.11 ¶5 All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration or is declared with the **`constexpr`** storage-class specifier shall be constant expressions or string literals

---

Note that as an extension to the standard, some compilers (e.g. gcc) allow you to use constant variables as a constant expression.

```c
const int a = 1;
const int b = 2;
const int c = 3;
int array[] = { a, b, c };   // Extension.

int main( void ) {
}
```

But this is not technically allowed.

Comment: Also, I specifically mentioned I was referring to lifetime (which is determined by storage duration).

Comment: This answer is not correct. C (unlike C++) makes no difference between `const` qualified variables and ordinary ones. What matters is the _storage duration_. Objects with static storage duration, as in both of your 2 first examples, need an initializer which is a constant expression - in this case an integer constant expression. Some mainstream compilers have managed to muck around with their own definition of constant expressions and claim that C allows implementation-defined forms of constant expressions. Which is debatable. If you ask me, both example 1) and 2) are not conforming.

Comment: If you test with older gcc like version 8 or so, they will not let either of the first 2 examples through. clang was always broken here. Neither gcc (13.x) nor clang (any version) are _strictly conforming_ for sure, nor do they offer a strictly conforming mode. Better compilers refuse both examples unconditionally.

Comment: @lundin, Adjusted.

Comment: @ikegami "the initializer must be constant expression." --> Does `int a = 1;
int b = 2; int *array[] = { &a, &b };`, as static variables, compile for you?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica C definitely allows address constants as initializers, so that's a different scenario and not even implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

C 2018 6.7.9 4 says:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

There are four storage durations: static, thread, automatic, and allocated.

- An object is static if its identifier is declared with `static` or is declared outside a function (some details omitted) without `_Thread_local`. To initialize a static object, a constant expression must be used.
- An object is thread local if its identifier is declared with `_Thread_local`.  To initialize a thread local object, a constant expression must be used.
- An object is automatic if it is defined inside a function without `static`. Non-constant expressions may be used to initialize an automatic object.
- An allocated object does not have an identifier because it is created using `malloc` or similar routine. C grammar does not provide any way to initialize such an object (values may be assigned to it, but that is different from initialization).

Comment: A great answer for the question asked by someone who just started learning C!! Go to primary school and use higher math definitions of natural numbers teaching counting from 1 to 15.

Comment: What's more relevant is what forms of constant expressions a certain compiler decides to let through. clang always let through `const` qualified variables as an implementation-defined form of constant expression during initialization. gcc started doing this too around version 10 somewhere, breaking compatibility with itself (although the C standard has not changed in this regard). And of course C++ always allowed `const` qualified variables as initializers so likely that's where it is coming from.